# I am currently working on an angular 16 application which uses ag grid version 28+. But table is not displaying

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

Angular version 16.2.6
Ag grid angular/community version 28.2.1

I have added proper width and height and also verified data is coming from backend. And styles are also imported properly. Still table is not displaying . Any idea ?

Comment: see this working : https://therichpost.com/angular-16-2-5-ag-grid-working-demo/

Comment: No it's not working